# Update Column using Loop in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hi I have a Table that have a Primary Key [UserId] now I have just added another Column called [ReferenceNumber].
And ReferenceNumber required to update values copied from UserId in reverse. 
For Example: if userId =12 then ReferenceNumber would be updated by 21.

I have to loop through end of the table and update ReferenceNumber column.

```
 FOR LOOP TO --- From First Row to End 
     Update dbo.UserTable SET [ReferenceNumber ]=
          (SELECT REVERSE([UserId]) FROM dbo.UserTable) 
 END
```

Please Advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
update dbo.UserTable
    set ReferenceNumber = reverse(UserId);
```

There is no need for an explicit "loop".  The `update` matches all matching rows in the table.